# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'Category'

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public partial class admin_category : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlDataSource sd = new SqlDataSource();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.UnobtrusiveValidationMode = System.Web.UI.UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;

        con.Open();

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" insert into Men Category (CategoryName) values (@CategoryName)",con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryName",Cat_nm.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        Response.Write("<script>alert('Category Added Sucessfully');</script>");

    }
}
```

Comment: `[Men Category]` <= if your object name has a space then wrap it with brackets. The same is true if your object name is a reserved word.

Comment: what is that 'Men' ?

Answer (score 0):

Having a space in your table/column/etc. names is generally a bad idea for exactly this reason.  Queries can easily become unparsable, and other tools interacting with the database could have a variety of issues dealing with this.  Best to remove the space.

If the name *must* have a space for some reason, you can identify it as a DB entity with square brackets:

```
insert into [Men Category] (CategoryName) values (@CategoryName)
```

In general it's a good habit to explicitly use these brackets to identify your tables/columns/etc. anyway, spaces or otherwise:

```
insert into [Men Category] ([CategoryName]) values (@CategoryName)
```

Answer (score -1):

you need [] for Men Category
    insert into [Men Category] (CategoryName) values ('some things')

Comment: How is this different from David's answer?